# how to have the title which contains the number direct?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a problem for the title for tableau

I want to get the title like :2018 Rolled Out: 1376000
how can I get it?

COPQ is a list of numbers which i create as a mesure

Here is the capture:

[image: capture]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that is because you have something on the detail shelf which is giving you a min to max range in the header.

Try taking another sheet named sheet 2 without the dimension on the detail shelf and take a running sum there in the header. then drag  sheet 2 to the dashboard as a header and your bar chart as the actual worksheet(sheet1)

[image]